# $f'(a) <0$ is enough to say that $f$ has a local maximum in $a$

Tags: functional-analysis, derivatives

Let's say we have a function $f:[a,b] \to \mathbb{R}$ which has a local maximum at $a$ and $f$ is derivatible in $a$. I want to prove that

1. $f'(a)\leq 0$
2. $f'(a) <0$ is enough to say that $f$ has a local maximum in $a$.

For the first one I have this:

Because $f$ has a local maximum in $a$, there exist a $\delta >0$ so that for every $x \in [a,b]$ with $|x-a| <\delta$, $f(a) \geq f(x)$.
We can see that for every $x \in [a,b]$ , $x \geq a$. I thought I could conclude out of this that $f'(a)\leq 0$

For the second one I'm stuck. I want to use the middle value theorem of lagrange on [a,x] for $x \in [a,b]$ randomly. But I can't really seem to prove it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $f^\prime(a) \lt 0$, then it exists $\delta \gt 0$ such that

$$\frac{f(a+h)-f(a)}{h} \lt k$$ for $h \in [0,\delta)$ where $k = \frac{f^\prime(a)}{2} \lt 0.$

Therefore for $h \in [0, \delta)$

$$f(a+h) \lt f(a) +kh \lt f(a)$$ because $k \lt 0$. Proving that $a$ is a local maximum.

Comment: I don't get it 100% why f(a+h)>f(a) gives that f has a local maximu.

Comment: @questmath there was a typo in my inequality that I fixed.

Comment: yes same question then for f(a+h)<f(a) , what makes it say that there is an local maximum?

Comment: This is the very definition of a local maximum: $f(a)$ is larger than $f(a+h)$ for $0 \le h \lt \delta$.

Answer (score 0):

Assume that $f’(a)<0$ so $\lim_{h\to 0} ( f(a+h)-f(a) ) / h<0$ so $$(f(a+h)-f(a))/h$$

will eventually be less than $0$( for all $h$ in an interval $(a,a+h)$)

)   .

So that would mean that $f(a)>f(a+h)$ implying that $f(a)$ is a local max on $(a,a+h)$

Note that $h$ will be positive since $a$ is a boundary point of the domain of the function .

Comment: I don't get how you have f(a+h)-f(a)/h?

Comment: That’s the derivative(quotient)

Comment: Isn't it $lim_{h \to 0} \frac{f(a+h)-f(a)}{h}$

Comment: Yes but if that is negative then the quotient will also be eventually negative

Comment: Yes but you still only derivate f(a)/h ?

Comment: I don’t understand the derivative of $f(x)$ at $a$ is $f(a+h)-f(a)/h$ as $h$ goes to $0$

Comment: That's not true, like I already said, lim of $\frac{f(a+h)-f(a)}{h}$, or did you mean to write the $h$ under f(a+h)-f(a) instead of only under f(a)?

Comment: @questmath Yes I have make it clearer

Comment: Alright I'm sorry then :)

Comment: @questmath is the argument clear now ?